# TextBlock border makes TextBlock move to another location

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to add a border to TextBlock, wrapping it into Border block.
But that makes TextBlock move to another window location. The same happens
if the TextBlock is wrapped into a Grid.

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF0B232F" BorderThickness="2" >
<TextBlock 
      Background="#FFCDCD5A"
        Grid.Column="4" 
        Grid.Row="2" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap"  
        Width="214.8"
         Height="261.4" >
</Border>
```

UPDATE

The problem with this  TextBlock It has spanned several grid rows.

First I did as suggested Daniel Marques. 
I have also had to add to Border definition these:
HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
and  Grid.RowSpan.

Also I had to delete the TextBlock margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when you place your TextBlock between the  markups you are actually saying that the TextBlock is the 'Child' of the Border. This means that the TextBlock will be enclosed by the border. So it is logical to assume that the TextBlock will "follow" the Border around. It will be displayed "inside" the Border wherever the Border is located.

You need to set the location of the Border instead of the TextBlock for it to appear where you'd like it to:

```
<Border Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="#FF0B232F" BorderThickness="2" >
<TextBlock 
    Background="#FFCDCD5A"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"  
    Width="214.8"
    Height="261.4" />
</Border>
```

Comment: Does not work for me probably because my TextBlock spans several grid rows. I have specified the grid row span but the result is the same.

Comment: You want your textblock to span several rows and it is not working? Once again, you need to set the Grid.RowSpan of the Border that is the parent of the TextBlock and not of the TextBlock itself.